# How do I get Highcharts chart redraw to move faster?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

What happens is that when the data set has more than 14 records, these arrows appear (see screenshot). When you click on the arrows, it modifies the data set + or - 1 record using this code:

```
                $('#left').click(function(){
                    if (show_min > 0) {
                        data_chart = $('#data-chart').highcharts();
                        data_chart.xAxis[0].update({
                            min: --show_min,
                            max: --show_max
                        });
                    }
                });
```

That part works great.

What I want to do is tweak the animation speed and easing to match the rest of the stuff on our site. Is this possible? I didn't see it in the API docs, but I'm sure I could have missed it somewhere.

[image: Screenshot:]

Comment: whoops. added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following link.  I believe "duration" is what you're looking for which is an option in the API.

[Highcharts - Animation Documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.animation)

> animation: Boolean|Object Set the overall animation for all chart
>   updating. Animation can be disabled throughout the chart by setting it
>   to false here. It can be overridden for each individual API method as
>   a function parameter. The only animation not affected by this option
>   is the initial series animation, see plotOptions.series.animation.
>
> The animation can either be set as a boolean or a configuration
>   object. If true, it will use the 'swing' jQuery easing and a duration
>   of 500 ms. If used as a configuration object, the following properties
>   are supported:
>
> duration - The duration of the animation in milliseconds.
>
> easing - A
>   string reference to an easing function set on the Math object.

So I'm guessing you will want something like this where you create your chart:

```
animation:{
  duration:100
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I couldn't find it!

Comment: I already have animation disabled and need to go faster. Like 20-30Hz ideally. Any idea for further optimisations? Found it, see: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/highcharts-high-performance-boost-module/